# How do you explicitly type refs which can attach to multiple types of elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component that renders some JSX with either a text area or an input text field depending on props. I want to explicitly type a ref to be able to attach to two different kinds of elements (textarea or input). How do I do this? I also need the type because I have to explicitly type the props again when the child receive it since I'm going to be passing it the ref as a prop in order to apply styles when the ref is focused.

I've tried

```
const fieldRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement | null>(null);
```

and

```
type FieldRefType<T extends HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement> = {
  current: T | null;
};
const fieldRef =
    useRef<FieldRefType<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>>(null);
```

but I keep getting errors that look like some variation of

```
Type 'RefObject<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLTextAreaElement> | undefined'.
```

Here is the relevant section in the code:

```
const FormField = ({ fieldType }: FormFieldProps): JSX.Element => {
  const fieldRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>(null);

  let placeholderText: string;
  switch (fieldType) {
    case "Name":
      placeholderText = "Enter your name";
      break;
    case "Email":
      placeholderText = "Enter your email address";
      break;
    case "Subject":
      placeholderText = "Enter the subject of your message";
      break;
    case "Message":
      placeholderText = "Enter your message";
      break;
    default:
      const _exhaustiveCheck: never = fieldType;
      return _exhaustiveCheck;
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles["label-field-container"]}>
      <label className={styles["label"]} htmlFor={fieldType}>
        {fieldType}
      </label>
      {fieldType === "Message" ? (
        <textarea
          className={`${styles["field"]} ${styles["field-large"]}`}
          id={fieldType}
          ref={fieldRef as React.RefObject<HTMLTextAreaElement>}
          placeholder={placeholderText}
          autoComplete="off"
          required
        ></textarea>
      ) : (
        <input
          className={styles["field"]}
          id={fieldType}
          ref={fieldRef as React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>}
          type="text"
          placeholder={placeholderText}
          autoComplete="off"
          required
        ></input>
      )}
      <FormFieldUnderline />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Edit: Doing `ref={fieldRef as React.RefObject<HTMLTextAreaElement>}` works, but something tells me it's a bad idea to use type assertion here. Is there a better way?

Edit 2: Using an intersection as in `const fieldRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement & HTMLTextAreaElement>(null);` will work since TS knows that there won't be any type errors. This would constrain the variable to only have access to properties on both types.

Comment: You want the ref type to depend on the prop, so when you check `fieldType === "Message"`, TS knows what kind of ref it is. Please see [mre] again. Your example code is good, but just very close to complete. It's much easier to read and understand if you just give the complete minimal code for the component instead of trying to save a few lines of code by cutting out and reordering things like here.

Comment: @super I've edited the code to make it a reproducible example. I'm not entirely sure what you're suggesting. How do you propose I modify the code to achieve the property that TS knows what kind of ref it is when I check `fieldType === "Message"` ?

Comment: I was thinking of using discriminating unions, but after some testing it seems hard to get it to work with the `useRef` call. So maybe you do need the type assertion.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the following: typescript expects that information flows from your component to `input` or `textarea`, and with refs its the other way around: these components get a reference to an object that they will modify and provide information to your component. Imagine if `fieldRef` was not a ref but just an object with some information that you pass to component `<Foo info={fieldRef} />` to work with. Imagine `Foo`'s `info` property type is set to `{ current: HTMLInputElement }` because `Foo` only knows how to work with `HTMLInputElement` objects, so it makes sense that if you pass an object of type `{ current: HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextareaElement }` there is an error: this objects purpose is to give information to `Foo` to work with and `Foo` doesn't know how to work with `HTMLTextareaElement`s. Refs have a different purpose, but there is no way to tell typescript "hey, the purpose of this object is not to pass information to `input` but to let `input` modify it".

So to type this you have to either use assertions, or pass function ref to `input` instead of ref object. This way it is unambiguous: you pass a function to `input` or `textarea` that they will call with either `HTMLInputElement` or `HTMLTextareaElement` and this functions knows how to work with both of those, so no error:

```
const fieldRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement | null>(null);
const setRef = (e: HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement) => fieldRef.current = e;

<input ref={setRef} />
<textarea ref={setRef} />
```

Or just inline it

```
const fieldRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement | null>(null);

<input ref={e => fieldRef.current = e} />
<textarea ref={e => fieldRef.current = e} />
```